# How to change the street view in google maps 3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Goal:** Get the **TEXT** address and then display the street view and map view at the same time

Ref Site:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple.html

My site:
http://www.iamvishal.com/dev/property/P2154 (pls click the map view to see the map)

Problem: I am able to display the map and the address correctly but instreet view does not change. Any idea why ?

My js variable address hold the text address in this case "323235 Balmoral Terrace Heaton Newcastle Upon Tyne"

```
function initialize() 
{
var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
var mapOptions = {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(
document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var panoramaOptions = {
    position: fenway,
    pov: {
         heading: 34,
         pitch: 10,
         zoom: 1
         }
   };

var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), 
panoramaOptions);

map.setStreetView(panorama);

var geocoderTwo = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoderTwo.geocode({"address":address},function(results, status)
{
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
   {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker
      ({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
   }
else
{
  alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
}
}


);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I've created a streetview before:

```js
function createStreetMap(strMapCanvasID, yourLatLng)
{
    var panorama;

    //once the document is loaded, see if google has a streetview image within 50 meters of the given location, and load that panorama
    var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

    sv.getPanoramaByLocation(yourLatLng, 50, function(data, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            //google has a streetview image for this location, so attach it to the streetview div
            var panoramaOptions = {
                pano: data.location.pano,
                addressControl: false,
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                }
            }; 
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById(strMapCanvasID), panoramaOptions);


            // lets try and hide the pegman control from the normal map, if we're displaying a seperate streetview map
            objCreatedMap.setOptions({
                streetViewControl: false
            });
        }
        else{
            //no google streetview image for this location, so hide the streetview div
            $('#' + strMapCanvasID).parent().hide();
        }
    });
}
```

**Update:** and you could call this function directly from within your existing code (I've amended the function to use a LatLng rather than individual latitude and longitude values:

```js
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
   {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker
      ({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

      createStreetMap('yourStreetViewDiv', results[0].geometry.location);
   }
```

Comment: how are you getting the intLat, intLong ? do u have the code for that

Comment: Could you just use your 'fenway' LatLng?

Comment: unfortunately no as I need to take a text string and then get the geocode geocoderTwo.geocode({"address":address},function(results, status)

Comment: Updated my answer showing how you could directly call the function from within your code when the geocoder request is successful

Comment: thanks it worked for me. Sorry for taking so long to update you.

Comment: Hi Duncan! I like what you did with the above code. I'm having some trouble on a similar project. I currently have a map and street view div attached by the control of the pegman. I also want to hide streetview if an image is not available. I was going to use your code but the map and street view don't seem to be linked (as in moving street view don't move pegman on the map). Can you take a look at my question here please - I'd hugely appreciate it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861392/can-i-modify-this-code-to-detect-whether-a-street-view-image-is-available-in-goo

Comment: creating a new instance every time you update the location will shoot up up your Google map monthly billing cost exponentially.
As Google charges for every new instance creation

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your code. Fix them first:

```
64 Uncaught ReferenceError: berkeley is not defined
```

Also, you'll need to set a `zoom` and `mapTypeId` options on your `Map` before anything shows.

Comment: Looks to me like he's already got zoom and mapTypeId on his mapOptions.

Comment: the problem is the street view is not updating when the page loads.I removed the problems on the code as per your