# Can I modify this code to detect whether a street view image is available in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have to admit, I wing it a bit with Google Maps API. A lot of copy and pasting and basic edits. This code works really well unless a street view image is not available. What is the easiest way to detect no image and hid the pano div? Or the other way round, display it if there is an image:

```
    function googleMap() {

       var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

          if (geocoder) {
              alert('<?php echo $phoneDirectory->Address; ?>');
             geocoder.geocode({ 'address': '<?php echo $phoneDirectory->Address; ?>' }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {


                  var googleLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                  var googleLong = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                  //alert(googleLat + ", " + googleLong);


                var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(googleLat,googleLong);
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: fenway,
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(
                    document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
                    var panoramaOptions = {
                        position: fenway,
                        pov: {
                        heading: 0,
                        pitch: 0
                    }
                };

                var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'),panoramaOptions);
                map.setStreetView(panorama);

                // **** ADDED TO GET WORKING!!! ***** 
                var client = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
                client.getPanoramaByLocation(fenway, 50, function(result, status) {
                    if (status == "ZERO_RESULTS") {

                        // Hide street view div
                        $('#pano').css("display", "none");


                    }

                });     

                googleMapLoaded = true;


                } 
                else {
                  alert('No results found: ' + status);
                }
             });
          }         

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewStatus)

If there are no nearby panoramas the result is `ZERO_RESULTS`

Comment: Managed to get it working, thanks for your prod. I had looked at the function/code before. I just didn't realise I could add it to my existing code, rather than edit or replace what I had. I've updated my source snippet with the whole lot now.

Comment: +1 on your question question because you took the extra step and pasted a working example.